# How to find sum of elements from iterator of type tuple in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm working with different functions and techniques in spark scala. I would like to find sum of first elements in a iterator of type (int, int) from scala spark

[image]

Please let me know what is the issue in above syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the map function, *x._2* is an iterator of (Int, Int), you need to use *map* to extract the first element from each tuple, then sum it:

```
wordCountsWithGroup.map(x => (x._1, x._2.map(_._1).sum)
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you use `groupByKey` - this is a really bad choice.

What you should really do is either `mapValues` followed by `reduceByKey`:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("first", (1, 1)), ("first", (1, 1))))

rdd.mapValues(_._1).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

or `aggregateByKey`

```
rdd.aggregateByKey(0)({ case (acc, (x, _)) => acc + x}, _ + _)
```

Comment: Thank you for good explanation. I wanted to understand different api's of spark and wanted to play around with them with different scenarios as I always get confused with groupByKey, reduceByKey, aggregateByKey